# Pass style to child component in material-ui-next

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

hi :) lets say i have two components one who has the text "orange" as a const and I want its child to have orange text.. using material-ui-next, i'm using withStyles and anything else just doesn't affect the color of the text... here is some code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Card, { CardActions, CardContent } from 'material-ui/Card';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';

const styles = {
  card: {
    minWidth: 275,
  },
  bullet: {
    display: 'inline-block',
    margin: '0 2px',
    transform: 'scale(0.8)',
  },
  title: {
    marginBottom: 16,
    fontSize: 14,
  },
  pos: {
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
};

function SimpleCard(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  const bull = <span className={classes.bullet}>•</span>;

  return (
    <div>
      <Card className={classes.card}>
        <CardContent>
          <Typography className={classes.title} color="textSecondary">
            Word of the Day
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="headline" component="h2">
            be{bull}nev{bull}o{bull}lent
          </Typography>
          <Typography className={classes.pos} color="textSecondary">
            adjective
          </Typography>
          <!-- I want the text from here to become orange-->
          <Typography component="p">
            well meaning and kindly.<br />
            {'"a benevolent smile"'}
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions>
          <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}

SimpleCard.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(SimpleCard);
```

orange will be at this.props.color 
I don't mind it being the object orange from "material-ui/colors/orange" I just want to somehow address that value from within my SimpleCard component and use it when building the styles (or ignore styles all together and just use the color)

Comment: When you use the withStyles HOC doesn't that just inject props. Do you need to still assign those styles to the different Dom elements?

Comment: its an example of a component i want to have orange text on not a component it didnt work on.. thanks tho :)

Comment: I dont understand your question..
you can simply have "style = {{color:this.props.color}}" in your child component!